# Rails, form_for and paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, form-for

Once again, i am having issues with form_for.

I have an activity model, and it look like:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :acdocs, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :acdocs,
                                reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['descr'].blank?},
                                allow_destroy: true
end
```

And i have an acdoc model.
acdoc is short for activity document. o read somewhere that if i used the word "document" i could have some issues with JavaScript... then best safe than sorry.

```
class Acdoc < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :activity
  has_attached_file :document

  validates_attachment :document,
                       :presence => true,
                     content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png", "application/pdf"] }
end
```

Since activity can have many acdocs, i use a form_for to handles that:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :acdocs do |acdocs| %>
    <div>
      <%= acdocs.label :descr" %>
      <%= acdocs.text_field :descr %>
      <%= acdocs.label :document %>
      <%= acdocs.file_field :document b%>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'add doc', :name => "add_item"  %>
  </p>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

And for the controller, i use this:

```
  def new
    @activity = Activity.new
    @activity.acdocs.build
  end
  def create
    @activity = Activity.new(activity_params)

    if params[:add_item]
      @activity.acdocs.build
      render :action => 'new'
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        if @activity.save
          format.html { redirect_to @activity, notice: 'Activity was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @activity }
        else
          format.html { render action: 'new' }
          format.json { render json: @activity.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end
  def update
    if params[:add_item]
      unless params[:activity][:acdocs_attributes].blank?
        for attribute in params[:activity][:acdocs_attributes].permit!
          @activity.acdocs.build(attribute.last.except(:_destroy)) unless attribute.last.has_key?(:id)
        end
      end
      @activity.acdocs.build
      render :action => 'edit'
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        if @activity.update(activity_params)
          format.html { redirect_to @activity, notice: 'Activity was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        else
          format.html { render action: 'edit' }
          format.json { render json: @activity.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

This setup, kinda work. If i "add_item" a bunch of fields and select the files, all of then get uploaded.

The issue for me is, when a user press add_item, or even, edit a saved activity, the form will open. With the itens, the attach file button and the text: "no file attached". I am sure this file is meant to only tell the user were the file is being uploaded from (from his own computer) rather than the file stored on the app... but this will make the user think that no file was uploaded.

How can i put a text saying that the file is there, when it is there?

Also, this is not the fist time i have similar problems with form for. Sometimes, i want to show something if the object is already on the database. or if its a new one. (like, show a "destroy checkbox" for existing items, but hide for new ones)

How can i do these things?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the file exists. For example, you can check if the file_name attribute is set in your db, something like this `acdoc.document?`, or you can check if the file actually exists on the filesystem, like this: `acdoc.document.exists?`

- `show_destroy_checkbox if acdoc.document?` or
- `show_destroy_checkobx if acdoc.document.exists?`

Cheers!

Comment: The thing is, i am inside an form_for. So, the document object i have inside it, inst the right object. It is an form-builder helper: undefined method `exists?' for <ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x000000032b9d70>